# Use class styles as inline styles?

Tags: html, css, class, inline

So a pretty basic question: is it "okay" to use classes like inline styles?

Basically what I've done is build a "bootstrap"; but instead of doing so by element, I've done it by property. So basically, the CSS is nothing but a set of pre-defined styles.

For example:

```
.margin-left-1 {margin-left:1px;}
.margin-right-1 {margin-right:1px;}
.bg-blue {background-color:blue;}
.padding-5 {padding: 5px;}
.radius-10 {border-radius:10px;}
.width-10 {width:10%;}
.width-10px {width:10px;}
.font-arial {font-family: 'Arial';}
```

etc.

This makes it so you can quickly & easily build the website and its styles right in the HTML. However, is this a bad practice? Should I simply have styles for things like border-radius, colors, buttons, etc and leave the padding, margin, etc. (general box layout properties) defined within classes/id's?

Comment: No, this is certainly not a good practice. Class names are meant to be meaningful.

Comment: what happens when you have elements with the class padding-5 and you decide you want all of those elements to have 7px padding? are you going to leave the name padding-5 the way it is but actually have it pad 7px? or are you going to look for every element on every page with class padding-5 and replace it with yoru new 'padding-7' css style? html is for 'content', css is for 'styling'.

Answer (score 3):

Its the exact opposite of what you are supposed to do. CSS selector names should nor represent selector content but rather the nature of the object they are supposed to describe (style). In other words selector names should be as abstract as possible in regards to how much they depend on the selector content itself.

Here is a practical problem which you will run into if you decide to use your system. What if you decide to change the value of your `margin-right` attribute for the `.margin-right-1` class? Following your logic you would now have to change its name to lets say `margin-right-10` and not only that but you would also be forced to update your complete HTML code in order to replace references to the `margin-right-1` with `margin-right-10` class.

However if you define a class selector named, lets say, `.wrapper` you could redefine its attributes later however you like.

Not only that but what will you do if your selector also has a `margin-left` attribute? Which one would become dominant in order to give name to that particular selector?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

You can then create so called "mixins" and use them in your styles. E.g.

```
.rounded-corners (@radius: 5px) {
  border-radius: @radius;
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
  -moz-border-radius: @radius;
}

#header {
  .rounded-corners;
}
#footer {
  .rounded-corners(10px);
}
```

Comment: The analogy is not quite right. If you are to demonstrate what would be wrong with using LESS the way OP intended then you would use `.rounded-corners-10 (@radius : 10px)` etc. not names without "embedded" values.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a lot of discussion about what constitutes a good class name.  Community consensus and the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes) itself suggest that your class names describe *what* the element is, not how it should look.

> There are no additional restrictions on the tokens authors can use in the class attribute, but authors are encouraged to use values that **describe the nature of the content, rather than values that describe the desired presentation of the content**.

Also see the [Semantic HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) page on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you then decide to use the same HTML for your mobile website, but a different stylesheet. Let's say you have an article container that you've set to 800px wide. Rather than having `.article {width: 800px}` you'll have `.width-800 {width: 400px}`. How confused will you be when trying to write and debug your new layout?

Also, maybe you don't want all elements that were 800px wide to now be 400px, just articles. So using your method, to target your article container, you'd have to chain together all the different classes that are used by it, e.g:

```
.float-left.border-solid-black.padding-10.bg-blue.font-arial.width-800 {
    width: 400px;
}
```

This much longer selector means that:

- It takes up more room (file-weight) in the CSS file, so slower page loads
- It's slower to parse nodes via XPath or JavaScript
- It's more *brittle* to changes, as you don't know if any other divs may be affected (if they happen to also have the same classes applied)
- It's much harder to debug and isolate bug-fixes  (not negatively impact other areas on the page by mistake)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to use classes to say what your text is, and then use CSS to say how such things should be displayed. This way if you decide you want your headings to have 0.5em of space beneath them instead of 0.3em of space, it's an easy thing (especially with a tool like FireBug).

Using them the way you've indicated isn't taking advantage of this separation. It's brittle and has no additional functionality beyond just putting inline styles all over the place.

That said, you will usually have a few utility classes like this (e.g. `.collapsed { display: none }`) for toggling and such.